# How to add category code in com.microsoft.graph.models.Message

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to add category code when `graphapi` reads the mail, for I am trying to use below code.

```
Message newMessage = new Message();
         newMessage.isRead = true;
         newMessage.importance = Importance.LOW;
         newMessage.categories = no idea how to add categoties!!!
         
         if(shouldFlag) {
             newMessage.flag =  message.flag;
             newMessage.flag.flagStatus = FollowupFlagStatus.FLAGGED;
         }
         
         _appClient.users(o365Mailbox)
             .messages(message.id)
             .buildRequest()
             .patch(newMessage);
    }
```

Need to know how can I add the category code when graph API reads the mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.microsoft.graph/microsoft-graph/latest/com/microsoft/graph/models/OutlookItem.html#categories), the type of `categories` is `List<String>`.

You could simply do :

```java
List<String> msgCategories = new ArrayList<>();
msgCategories.add("category1");
msgCategories.add("category2");
newMessage.categories = msgCategories;
```

Replace `"category1"` and `"category2"` with default categories or with the name of your own custom categories.

Comment: Thanks @Tom,  I need to check like in this link:- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/666330/microsoft-graph-api-filtering-on-categories                         how can add the color to that mail after processing .I Need to assign category code to email after email gateway successfully processed.